# Can I license a VMWare 15 still?

Tags: windows-7, vmware, vmware-workstation

Work in manufacturing, had to setup a Windows XP VM on an old Windows 7 box which is all that is available.

Windows 7 supports VMWare workstation 15, which is what we have installed and is running our XP VM.

However, it seems like you can only buy licenses for VMWare 17?  My coworker bought a 17 license and tried to use it on 15 but it is getting rejected.  Is there any way to still license VMWare Workstation 15?  Or is there a legitimate marketplace to still buy a Workstation 15 license?

Comment: It is not possible to purchase VMWARE Workstation 15 in 2023 directly from VMWARE. If you find it on another marketplace, be careful of scams, as most out of date software for sale are typically scams. I assume you tried installing Windows XP on a VM created by VMWARE Workstation 17?

Comment: This is restore job.  My coworker actually has VMWare 15 iirc on his work computer and did all of this.  Made a new VM-> Windows XP, then we had it boot with clonezilla ISO, restored our image, and then when we finally got the box to it was going to go on he moved it to there into a VMWare Workstation 15.

In the event I'm wrong and he originally set this up with Workstation 17 does that change anything?

Is there nothing we can do with this?

Comment: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/90060#:~:text=Note%3A%20Windows%207%20hosts%20are,required%20for%20each%20virtual%20machine     ...... Note: Windows 7 hosts are no longer supported, Workstation 17 will not function on them.

Comment: @John I know that is the crux of the issue I am trying to overcome, a way to license Workstation 15 as we are stuck with this windows 7 box.

Comment: Windows XP runs as a guest in VMware V17 (I have this running) so you will need to upgrade the Host machine.

Comment: Try contacting VMWare Sales with the key that was bought for VMWare 17, they should be able - if they want to - to downgrade it to the VMWare 15 key.

Comment: @YisroelTech Ok that is good news.  We've tried reaching out to them but ultimately we just get a contact form and have yet to get a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My coworker was able to downgrade the license directly through VMWare.com after logging in with the account that purchased it.  First he had to downgrade it from 17 to 16.  Then he was able to downgrade it from 16 to 15.  Then it the new license key it gave did work for his software.  Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can still find VMware Workstation 15 licenses and software on
internet, although you should check very carefully the vendor.

For example, you can search
[on amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=VMware+Workstation+15&crid=3A90LBOS9KFY1&sprefix=vmware+workstation+15%2Caps%2C143&ref=nb_sb_noss_2),
where the vendors are evaluated on past purchases
(hopefully not faked ones).

There also exist many doubtful downloads, but this is not recommended,
so be careful when searching.